# Factorization of a polynomial using synthetic division

Tags: polynomials

Factorize:
$$x^4-x^3-19x^2+49x-30$$[image]

In the figure above, I have showed upto where I tried? Can anyone help me to complete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, suppose $G(x)=x^3-19x+30$ and note that $G(2)=0$.

So $(x-2)$ is a factor of $G(x)$ by the factor theorem.

By synthetic division, we get $$\color{red}{G(x)=(x-2)(x^2+2x-15)}$$

Again, suppose $H(x)=x^2+2x-15$ and note that $G(3)=0$.

So $(x-3)$ is a factor of $G(x)$ by the factor theorem.

By synthetic division, we get $$\color{orange}{H(x)=(x-3)(x+5)}$$

So we can write that $$\color{blue}{x^4-x^3-19x^2+49x-30=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x+5)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$Q(x)=x^3-19x+30$

$1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30|30$ and, for example, $2^3-19\cdot2+30=8-38+30=0$

Then $x^3-19x+30=(x-2)Q_1(x)$

Solutions: $-5;1;2;3$. Then $x^4−x^3−19x^2+49x−30=(x+5)(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$

Comment: This is already the solution. You should give the OP a hint how to continue.

Answer (score 0):

Search another root of the polynomial under the divisors of $30$, you will find $2$, then you can divide again to get a polynomial with degree $2$.

This can be solved with the quadratic formula.

If you know all the roots, it is easy to factor the polynomial. It turns out that in this case all roots are integers, so the polynomial splits into linear factors.